# How to pass single element safearray to COM function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, com, safearray

I have an out of process COM server which provides a function f with the following signature:

```
f = void f(handle, int32, SafeArray(int32), SafeArray(int32))
```

When I try

```
h = actxserver('Server.Object.1');
x0=int32([0 0]);
y0=int32([0 0]);
h.f(int32(0), x0, y0)
```

Everything works fine. But

```
h = actxserver('Server.Object.1');
x0=int32([0]);
y0=int32([0]);
h.f(int32(0), x0, y0)
```

Gives the error message

```
Error using COM.Server_Object_1/f
Error: Type mismatch, argument 2

Error in test (line 4)
h.f(int32(0), x0, y0)
```

I also tried the feature

```
feature('COM_SafeArraySingleDim', 0 or 1)
```

which had no effect.
I have the feeling that it worked in some earlier version of MATLAB, but I am not sure. Currently I am using 2019b.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: What gives that error? errors have more information than what you shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mathworks tech support, it is not possible. I ended up wrapping the function in a c++ mex file.